# Code Infilling fine-tuning with llama code

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I have a dataset of java methods and I want to fine-tune a code llm to provide accurate method names. Right now the dataset is in a .txt format with methods in text separated by a delimiter(###del###).
To do this I thought about using CodeLLaMa and more specifically code infilling.
From the original documentation:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import transformers
import torch

model_id = "codellama/CodeLlama-7b-hf"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16
).to("cuda")

prompt = '''def remove_non_ascii(s: str) -> str:
    """ <FILL_ME>
    return result
'''

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")["input_ids"].to("cuda")
output = model.generate(
    input_ids,
    max_new_tokens=200,
)
output = output[0].to("cpu")

filling = tokenizer.decode(output[input_ids.shape[1]:], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(prompt.replace("<FILL_ME>", filling))
```

If i set  `max_new_tokens=4` and replace method name with `<FILL_ME>` i will get a valid method name when i Inference the model.
My problem is with fine-tuning.
How am i supposed to format the dataset (as a supervised task) to fine tune such a model?